# How to click a chessground piece with cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress, e2e-testing

I am trying to click a piece on the [chessground board](https://github.com/lichess-org/chessground) with cypress.

For some reason, it's not triggering a click event.

I'm assuming it has something to do with how chessground binds clicks, or something svg related?

I've tried several things:

```
    cy.get("cg-board")
      .should("be.visible")
      .trigger("mousedown", offset.x, offset.y, {
        force: true,
      });
    cy.get("svg.cg-shapes")
      .should("be.visible")
      .trigger("mousedown", offset.x, offset.y, {
        force: true,
      });
    cy.get("svg.cg-custom-svgs")
      .should("be.visible")
      .trigger("mousedown", offset.x, offset.y, {
        force: true,
      });
    cy.get("div.cg-wrap")
      .should("be.visible")
      .trigger("mousedown", offset.x, offset.y, {
        force: true,
      });
    cy.get("piece.white.pawn:nth(1)")
      .should("be.visible")
      .trigger("mousedown", { force: true });

    cy.get("cg-board").should("be.visible").click(offset.x, offset.y, {
      force: true,
    });
    cy.get("svg.cg-shapes").should("be.visible").click(offset.x, offset.y, {
      force: true,
    });
    cy.get("svg.cg-custom-svgs")
      .should("be.visible")
      .click(offset.x, offset.y, {
        force: true,
      });
    cy.get("div.cg-wrap").should("be.visible").click(offset.x, offset.y, {
      force: true,
    });
    cy.get("piece.white.pawn:nth(1)")
      .should("be.visible")
      .click({ force: true });
```

When debugging, it seems to be clicking:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that it's ignoring non-trusted events:

https://github.com/lichess-org/chessground/issues/267#issuecomment-1609845364

Drag has this line:

```
if (!e.isTrusted || (e.button !== undefined && e.button !== 0)) return;
```